# Installation through proxy

Tags: 7, installation, proxies

I am using Drupal 7 and need to make the installer work through a proxy.

I can access the installation through my proxy at `https://my.proxy/install.php?profile=myprofile&locale=en`, but the JS and CSS files fails to load, Error code(404).

Which files do I need to modify to fix the installation page through the proxy?